# Flex app to load a pdf form in flash, fill it and download as pdf

Tags: flash, apache-flex, pdf, forms, acrobat

I'd like to write a simple flex app that works like the 
pdfescape.com service.
(you can try it without registering at www.pdfescape.com)

Here the steps I need to implement

1) User upload a pdf form

2) The form is converted in a a flash form

3) User fill the form (using a flash app)

4) User download the filled form as pdf document

Does anybody have some advices to start ? 
For step 2 I have found many pdf to flash converter but I need to leave the form editable.

thanks for your patience

Andrea

Answer (score 0):

Flash cannot render PDF files, so there would be a fair amount of work that needs to be done on the server and to dynamically parse and build the form within flex.

Off the top of my head:

The PDF to Flash converter probably creates images or formatted text displayed in it own reader?

1) User uploads form.

2) Server parses form using a PDF library to get list of fields (saved to DB)

3) Flex app builds form to be filled in, saved to DB

4) Server fills in form fields using PDF library and saves for download.

Hope this helps...

Comment: On pdfescape.com the layout of the flash form showed is exactly the same of the uploaded pdf document. So I think there should be some library to do the job. Parsing the pdf form to find the field list is quite easy, while recreate the pdf layout in a flash app is harder without any specific Api

Comment: Indeed, formatting layout in flash would fairly difficult and not an exact science, I would suggest not trying to format it the same using this route.

Comment: I wonder if its possible to open the PDF form dirrectly from the server using WebDav, not sure if the full version of Acrobat would be required tho?